# Show that the order of G = order f(G) times order ker(G).

Tags: group-theory

Let $f:G \rightarrow G'$ be a homomorphism and let $H$ be the kernel of $G$.  Suppose $G$ is finite.  Show ord$(G)=$ord$(f(G)) \cdot $ord$(H)$.

What I want to do is to construct a bijection, $\Phi$ from $G$\ $H$ (the factor group) to $f(G)$.

This should then tell me, I think, that ord$(G$\ $H)$ = ord$(f(G))$, which I can then use because ord$(G)=$ord$(G$\ $H)\cdot $ord$(H)$.

My problem is I'm not certain how to define the bijection.  I think I want it to be something like $\Phi : aH \mapsto a$ or $\Phi : aH \mapsto f(a)$ such that $a \in G$.  Which one should I choose and then when chosen should I just show it's well-defined and a bijection?

Comment: The second one ($G/H\rightarrow G^\prime,$ $aH\mapsto f(a)$) is the right one.

Comment: Btw: You get "$\mapsto$" by writing "\mapsto".

Comment: Thank, I'll edit it now.  I just wasn't sure of the code.

Comment: You will probably re-prove the usual isomorphism theorem as an intermediary step. Are you sure you can't use this theorem to begin with?

Answer (score 0):

The elements of the quotient $G/H$ ($H$ is a normal subgroup) are cosets $gH$ for some $g\in H$. You can define the bijection this way:
\begin{align*}\bar f\colon G/H &\longrightarrow f(G)\\gH&\longmapsto f(g)
\end{align*}
This map is well-defined (i.e.  the image does not depend on the representative in the class) since $ gH=f^{-1}\bigl(f(g)\bigr)$. It's not hard to check it is a group homomorphism, and it is bijective by construction.